# Issue with Scikit-learn data analysis

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pca

am attempting to take a .dat file of about 90,000 data lines of two variables (wavelength and intensity) and apply a sklearn.pca filter to it.

Here is a small set of that data:

```
wavelength                intensity
   [um]                 [W/m**2/um/sr]
196.078431372549       1.108370393265022E-003
192.307692307692       1.163428008597600E-003
188.679245283019       1.223639983609668E-003
```

The code I am using to analyze the data is below

```
pca= PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(data)
print(pca.components_)
```

The error code I get is this when I try to apply 2 pca components to one of the data sets:

```
ValueError: Datatype coercion is not allowed
```

Any help resolving would be much appreciated

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case, the problem is the column name, especially `[W/m**2/um/sr]`.

Also when using PCA, do not forget to rescale the input variables into "comparable" units using `StandardScaler`.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

data = pd.DataFrame({'wavelength [um]': [196.078431372549, 1.108370393265022E-003, 192.307692307692], 'intensity [W/m**2/um/sr]': [1.163428008597600E-003, 188.679245283019, 1.223639983609668E-003]})

scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=True, with_std=True)
pca= PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(scaler.fit_transform(data))
print(pca.components_)
```

Worked well for me. Maybe you just need to specify:

```
data.columns = data.columns.astype(str)
```

Comment: so with the data variable you created, is it possible to make it an array instead of listing each value?

Comment: @domryan what do you mean by "instead of listing each value"? You can indeed store the principal components of PCA (i.e. the "new variables") in an array and use it for further analysis.
(Don't forget to validate the response if it helped.)